# Using \StrSubstitute inside \embedfile is not working

Tags: xstring, embedfile

I'm using the following code:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{embedfile}

%\newcommand{\underscorefix}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{_}{\_}} <-- not working
\newcommand{\underscorefix}[1]{#1}
\embedfile[filespec=name_1.dat,ucfilespec={\underscorefix{name_1.dat}},mimetype=application/octet-stream]{source_dir_1/name_1.dat}
```

How can I replace the underscore with backslash underscore for the `ucfilespec` option?

The reason for that is that I would like to have a command like that:

```
\newcommand{\datafile}[2]{\embedfile[filespec={#2},ucfilespec={\underscorefix{#2}},mimetype=application/octet-stream]{#1#2}}
```

Comment: Please provide complete MWE. Also, when you say it is "not working," do you mean that compile halts with an error, or that it hangs indefinitely, or that it produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Do you *need* to escape the underscore? I made an experiment passing `name_1.dat` to the `ucfilespec` key and I get this in the (uncompressed) PDF file: `<</Type/Filespec/F(name_1.dat)/UF(name_1.dat)/EF<</F 1 0 R>>>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `stringmethod=escape` option for `\embedfile` solved the problem.

Complete code:

```
\usepackage{embedfile}
\newcommand{\datafile}[2]{\embedfile[filespec={#2},ucfilespec={#2},mimetype=application/octet-stream,stringmethod=escape]{#1#2}}
```

Now the `filespec` and the `ucfilespec` contains underlines. Before just the `filespec`.